# Mail Merge - Adding space for response

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word-2016, mail-merge

I am working on a word document into which we are merging excel data. We need to have either a line or some space when a field is blank. The merged form will be distributed for members to review the data on file and fill in any blank fields.

I have played around with IF statements and we are not getting the results we need. Here is an example of a line..

AM Bus: «AMBus»     PM Bus: «PMBus»          DOB: «Student_Date_of_Birth»

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD AMBus  } = "" "__________" { MERGEFIELD AMBus } }
```

Show us your IF statement attempts and we can troubleshoot them.  Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to see all your merge info codes

Addendum:  I'm running office365 with version 1808 (Build 10730.20280 Click-to-Run) and this works great for me.

Full replication:

```
Create xlsx file with one column.  header=name, row1=steve, row2=(blank), row3=dave
create new docx. Type some stuff.
- Menu <mailings>
- tool bar <select recipients>
- <use an existing list>
- <choose list and sheet>
- tool bar <rules> (under Write&Insert Fields)
- <If...then...else>
- field name "name"
- comparison "is blank"
- Compare to (nothing)
- Insert this text "________"
<OK>
ALT+F9
place cursor inside the last set of double quotes "|"
- tool bar <insert Merge field>
- <name>
- tool bar <finish and merge>
- edit individual documents
<DONE>
```

Final docx:

```
Print the following name merge style: { IF { MERGEFILED name }= "" "__________" "{ MERGEFIELD name }" }
```

Comment: I think the issue is with Word 2016. None of the standard things seem to work. The only place I am finding anything line mergefield stuff is in rules and then it is a box with options.

Comment: @ACJennings I updated my post to show how I do this.  So yes, you found the box with options, fill in as above.  Hopefully it helps